# Web Scraping links and dates from html table from 3gpp website

Tags: php, html, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract/scrap Zip Links and corresponding Date from the below Link's Release tab:

[3GPP report Website](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1387).

I am able to extract Zip links using the below php code:

```
preg_match_all('/<ul class=\"rpRootGroup\">(.*?)<\/ul/s',$specpage,$zipul);
$specul = new domDocument;
@$specul->loadHTML($zipul[0][0]);
$specul->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpathspecul = new DOMXPath($specul);
$rowsUL = $xpathspecul->query('//tr');
$resultul = array();
$zipf = array();
$zipuni = array();

foreach ($rowsUL as $rowul) {
    $colsul = $rowul->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($colsul as $colul) {

        if($xpathspecul->evaluate('count(.//a)', $colul) > 0) { // check if an anchor exists
            $slinkul = $xpathspecul->evaluate('string(.//a/@href)', $colul); // if there is, then echo the href value
        }
        if (isset($slinkul) && $slinkul!=null){
            $resultul[] = $slinkul;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($resultul as $ziplink){
    $chkzip = pathinfo($ziplink, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($chkzip == 'zip' && $ziplink!==null){
        $zipf[] = trim($ziplink);
    }
}
$zipuni = array_values (array_unique($zipf));
```

> $specpage contains the website loaded using curl

[Sample image of aforementioned Zip link and Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr37v.png)

However, I am not able to extract Corresponding Dates.

**Further, i am having problem with using 'array_unique' as there can be same Zip link but with different corresponding date. However, without 'array_unique' im getting a lot of multiple links.**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your literally just trying to grab the date(00-00-0000) and zip url from the page given, you could just use this below. You could easily put this into one Regex but it's clearer to see how it's working using two. As the Regex queries are so specific, I was getting precisely 21 matches per query, so it was just a matter of creating an additional array with keys so the data can be sorted with ease.

```
$url = 'https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=1387';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/.*\.zip/', $data, $links);
preg_match_all('/<\/td><td>\s*(\d*-\d*-\d*)\s*<\/td><td>/', $data, $dates);
$newArr = []; //Your new array with URL and Dates 

foreach($dates[0] as $k=>$v) {

    $newArr[] = ['date' => $v, 'url' => $links[0][$k]];
    echo 'Date: ' . $newArr[$k]['date'] . '<br>URL: ' .  $newArr[$k]['url'] . '<br><br>';
    //echo is for testing purposes. 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Date: 2015-12-18
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-d00.zip

Date: 2014-09-26
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-c00.zip

Date: 2012-09-21
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-b00.zip

Date: 2011-04-05
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-a00.zip

Date: 2009-12-18
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-900.zip

Date: 2008-12-18
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-800.zip

Date: 2007-06-21
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-700.zip

Date: 2005-01-06
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-600.zip

Date: 2004-04-01
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-530.zip

Date: 2003-10-02
URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/26_series/26.073/26073-520.zip

etc....
```

I've spot checked the data and the dates match up perfectly with the links.

Comment: Very good.  I did not know what he was trying to extract from the page. I could not decipher the image.   The reason the  XML was not working is there were too many HTML markup errors.  So I isolated the HTML for each of the 33 tables. Even the tables had too many HTML markup errors for the XML to work.